# How to prevent new window for AD B2C login with React

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c, aad-b2c

I am following the tutorials provided by Microsoft to try the AD B2C authentication flows using redirect, but this always opens a new browser tab to present Microsoft's login screen. This breaks the user experience we want to provide in our app. Is it possible to configure MSAL to redirect within the same frame/window without opening a new window or tab?

The other option from Microsoft is to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow but this is NOT recommended by Microsoft and it also does not have the flexibility to support use cases such as MFA.

Any recommendations to overcome the redirect issue are appreciated!

Comment: Post your code that creates the new tab. Link to the sample you’re using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "new browser tab" but you can use [iframes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) "for a simpler sign-in experience.

You can avoid redirecting users to a separate sign-in page or generating a pop-up window. By using the inline frame element , you can embed the Azure AD B2C sign-in user interface directly into your web application".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found a solution to the problem. Microsoft documentation from learn.microsoft.com points to the use of acquireTokenRedirect, which causes the new browser window to open and presents the Azure AD B2C Sign-in UI. However, I found that the github pages for MSAL library uses loginRedirect that uses the same frame and does not open a new window.

Comment: @ user716222 : how were you able to solve the problem with authentication flows ?I am also using loginPopup and whenever the browser is full screen it always opens a new window which does not even close after authentication. However if the browser is not full screen then the popup modal opens up. I want to use the popup modal.